# A uploaded file is 0 byte on Amazon S3 using django

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I've symbolic linked a S3 directory on my EC2 server. But a uploaded file was 0 byte when I uploaded file. It was work well before (I used just web server directory)

I don't have any idea dealing with this problem. Does anybody have a trouble like this problem on S3?

Thanks,

Comment: How exactly did you create this symlink? S3 is **not** a block store. I'm guessing you're using s3fs - in which case, this will likely never work.

Comment: I fixed this problem. I share to fix this for someone.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269081/a-upload-file-is-0byte-on-django/9387858#9387858

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't what you want to hear, but trying to interact with S3 via s3fs is a road fraught with pain and suffering.

Use HTTP to get objects into and out of S3. That's the way Amazon designed S3, and that's what will always be guaranteed to work in a sane, predictable fashion. You're using Django - so just install the Python Boto library and use that to put/get files as needed.

Comment: Should I use it? Because I'd like to use default Django Model. Thanks.

Comment: My answer is clear - you should use nothing other than http calls with S3.

Comment: Do you have a good example Boto with django? Thanks,

Comment: No, that would be a better question for Stackoverflow.